# Python multiprocessing. Finish all processes at the same time

Tags: python, locking, multiprocessing, semaphore, psycopg2

My goal is upload some data to database. I'm using psycopg2 and it has a rule: all processes must have own database connection. In my case it means that I must commit in worker. The problem is that I can commit only all processes finish sql insert command. What I need:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def worker1(s):    
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mydb user=postgres")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    pg_cursor.execute(
            """ insert into "MyTable1"("Column1")
                values(%s)""", [1])

    #wait all processes
    conn.commit()       

def worker2(s):    
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mydb user=postgres")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    pg_cursor.execute(
            """ insert into "MyTable2"("Column1")
                values(%s)""", [1])

    #wait all processes
    conn.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=worker1)
    p2 = Process(target=worker2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

How can I make all process wait untill finish sql commands? What is correct way to do this?
This sql insert only for example, in real task i need to insert millions of records.

Comment: Call ``.join()`` on the processes.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, join make the main process wait until all subprocesses finish. But I need that subprocesses wait each other. I shown the place in worker where i need to pause subprocess.

Comment: The example I've provided is a guide only. You'd have to work out the best flow of events for your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pair of [`multiprocessing.Event`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event) objects to allow both workers to tell the other that they're done, as well as to force them to wait for the other to signal back:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Event

def worker1(s, my_e, other_e):    
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mydb user=postgres")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    pg_cursor.execute(
            """ insert into "MyTable1"("Column1")
                values(%s)""", [1])

    #wait all processes
    my_e.set()
    other_e.wait()
    conn.commit()       

def worker2(s, my_e, other_e):    
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mydb user=postgres")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    pg_cursor.execute(
            """ insert into "MyTable2"("Column1")
                values(%s)""", [1])

    #wait all processes
    my_e.set()
    other_e.wait()
    conn.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e1 = Event()
    e2 = Event()
    p1 = Process(target=worker1, args=(e1, e2))
    p2 = Process(target=worker2, args=(e2, e1))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Just be careful about the possibility of a deadlock if one of the workers fails for some reason. You may want to set the optional `timeout` keyword argument of `Event.wait` to some fairly high value, and rollback if it expires. That or use a `try`/`except` in each worker that guarantees `my_e` gets `set()`, but also share a variable between the two workers that can be used to tell the other worker if a failure occurred.